# "Property does not exist on type component" error Angular template

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have a file, `platforms.ts`, where is declared an array as following :

```
export const platforms: Platforms[] = [
  {
    name: 'Instagram',
    value: 'instagram'
  },
  {
    name: 'Facebook',
    value: 'facebook'
  }
];
```

I try to import that array in my Angular component in order to use it in an `*ngFor`, such as :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let platform of platforms">
  <!-- displaying platform informations -->
</ng-container>
```

The thing is : it works when the `platforms` object is declared directly in my .ts file, but when I import it like
`import { platforms } from '../utils/platforms';`
I get the error :

`Property 'platforms' does not exist on type 'CampaignFormComponent'.`

A quick&dirty workaround is to declare an attribute platform in my typescript file, such as `platform /* class attribute */ = platform /* imported */` ; is there any cleaner way to do this ?

Comment: Not really. The template only has access to the component class variables and the imports happen outside of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No, there is no other way to do this.

Every variable you wish to use in your component html you must declare in your component class.